# How to install ubuntu with intel optane memory?

Tags: 22.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and i want to use ubuntu as host system. My system has intel optane memory. i want to use ubuntu with optane memory. there are some solutions how to configure it but i'm unable to install. facing issue while installing it. I need some one-to-one help to install ubuntu with optane memory. please help me out.

Comment: What specific problem do you have that has led you to seek help? "unable to install" is much too vague to offer useful advice.

Comment: I follow these steps but in my output i am unable to use optane as a cache.
https://codenotary.com/blog/ubuntu-how-to-use-intel-optane-memory-for-ssd-caching @user535733

Comment: That's fairly advanced stuff, mostly because of your hardware choice. Optane is proprietary, which makes things much harder. Are you open to the simpler solution of just using both storage devices as normal storage devices? Do you **need** the advanced caching feature?

Comment: can we talk in personal?

Comment: All help is public. Only public.

Comment: i started from start. My system has windows 11 64bit pre-installed with 16gb optane memory. now i want to use ubuntu as my host os. basically i want to use optane memory  with ubuntu as a cache device. when i found the mentioned post, i followed but somewhere i do some mistake so that the final installation result not same as a post.

Comment: if it need some advance configuration so please help me to do this.

Comment: yes on bare metal. I have installed ubuntu on VM many times.

Comment: Intel has obsoleted Optane. I have seen users replace Optane module with M.2 SSD or NVMe (not sure what works). 16GB is not really a lot. What is main drive. If SSD, then using Optane will not add much. Windows only uses it for Hibernation & boot, not as cache. Used Intel App in Windows to disable Optane, need AHCI driver in Windows.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373&p=14022735#post14022735 & 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/intel-optane-memory-and-storage-management/9mzng5hzwz1t?activetab=pivot:overviewtab